# Writing a loop with a range of dates

Tags: r, rstudio

I have an R script that is automated to run daily. Problem is, turns out there was a small error in the final output causing me to need to run the past two months again. Seeing how the massive size of the file prevents me from doing one pull at a time, I need to devise a script that does it on a daily basis. Here is what the script would look like if I ran it today:

```
    user_query = paste("SELECT
          i.value_1,
          c.value_2     
          FROM logs.imp i
          LEFT JOIN
          logs.click c
          ON i.id = c.id
          WHERE i.event_date = DATE('2018-08-23')
          AND i.advertiser_id IN (", paste(id_query$user_id, collapse = ", "), ")
          GROUP BY 1,2
          ;", sep = '')

results_query <- dbGetQuery(con,  user_query)

currentDate <- Sys.Date()

txtUserQuery <- paste("/home/jsmith/user_query_", currentDate,".txt",sep="")

write.table(user_query, file = txtUserQuery, sep = "|")

outputDir <- "/Users/jsmith"
outputFileName <- paste("user_query_", currentDate,".txt",sep="")
outputFile <- paste(outputDir, outputFileName, sep = "/")

handle <- getCurlHandle()
ftpUpload(what = outputFile, to = paste("ftp://ftp@ftp.xxx.com/Up/user_query_", currentDate,".csv",sep=""), userpwd = "xxxx:xxxxx", curl = handle)
```

Note the `WHERE i.event_date = DATE('2018-08-23')` line which is part of a SQL query that runs. What I need to do is devise a loop that runs that script but for every date going back to `2018-07-01`. So that means not only is the aforementioned line impacted, but also any instance involving the `currentDate <- Sys.Date()` part.

So if you have `WHERE i.event_date = DATE('2018-08-23')`, then the `CurrentDate` variable should be `2018-08-23`, allowing the `txtUserQuery` to look like `"/users/jsmith/user_query_2018-08-23.txt"` So on `2018-07-01` the CurrentDate would be stored as `2018-07-01` and it would be `"/users/jsmith/user_query_2018-07-01.txt"` (as well as in the initial `PASTE` for the `user_query` and so on with every date.

Comment: Is `currentDate` supposed to be the same as the query `event_date`?

`seq.Date(as.Date('2018-08-23'), as.Date('2018-07-01'), by = -1)` will give you a vector of each day between the two dates you mention. You could loop over that vector, but I'm not totally clear if that is what you are asking for

Comment: Good question. Sorry for not being clear. The answer is yes, though it doesn't need the `'` or parentheses surrounding it. So if you have `WHERE i.event_date = DATE('2018-08-23')`, then the `CurrentDate` variable should be `2018-08-23`, allowing the `txtUserQuery` to look like `"/users/jsmith/user_query_2018-08-23.txt"` So on `2018-07-01` it would be `"/users/jsmith/user_query_2018-07-01.txt"` and so on with every date.

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible, so I can't run to test, but it looks like you need to convert all hard-coded dates to one single variable, then loop over that vector I mentioned to change the date in each iteration.

Comment: @astrofunkswag - What do you mean? How so?

Comment: `for(d in dates) {

  currentDate <- d
  
  ...
  
}`